# Difference between UIImageView.hidden and UIImageView.image = nil

Tags: ios, performance, uiimageview

In my view, I have multiple views (`UICollectionViewCell`s) that, depending on the model, can include an `UIImageView` as a subview (each with a separate instance).

For my case, the views that don't show the `UIImageView` outnumber the ones that do show it.

I can choose to either call `UIImageView.hidden = false` when I want the views to show the image, or to set the image inside the image view i.e. `UIImageView.image = UIImage(named: ...)`.

I'm wondering, which is the more performant approach, with memory and speed concerns? I have a feeling that the difference is not significant enough, especially with `UIImage(named:)`'s caching, but I do want to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. if you set `UIImageView.image = nil`, then surely if an image is in memory, it will be released (then reallocated if reused), so I suggest always to do it
2. if you want to be sure that `UIImageView.image` (1) will not be visible, (2) does not occupy a `frame` in the `cell` and (3) will not imply rendering time, then also set `UIImageView.hidden = true`

I suggest to take both actions. Performances are not a problem here, in my opinion (considering also that you have very few cells with image inside)

Answer (score 0):

**nil** - this action implies that what was allocated by the `imageview` will be deallocated from memory.

**hidden** - `imageview` is still pointing to that memory location, but it has been hidden within its parent view.